# Haskell Stack Image Container Execute On Docker run

Tags: haskell, docker, haskell-stack

I am following the turorials from stackage and docker to run a haskell build via docker.

Building and Image creation works well and i can run the app via `docker run -p 5000:5000 {imagename} {app-exe}`

I am using the build in features of the latest stack to create the docke image with this minimal configuration.

```
image:
    container:
       base: "fpco/ubuntu-with-libgmp"
```

How can i make the image to launch the executable automatically, so that i can just type `docker run -p 5000:5000 {imagename}`. I know how to do it in a dockerfile but not with stack. I was thinking that I have to use:

```
entrypoints:
      - appname-exe
```

No success, no matter if I just use the name of executable or the absolute path to it. Maybe I don't understand what the entrypoint is for.

I am using Docker for Mac.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Cheers
Bjorn

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration/)? In particular, the `run-args` field and the `--docker-run-args` flag?

Comment: Yes I did, the problem is not the running of the app via stack, the problem is when i create the image and then later run it via docker. Can't see how the run-args would help me there, in particular when i later compose the app in a docker stack.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out myself. Everything is working correctly, I just didn't understand that stack creates two separate images. One just for the environment and one for the entrypoint.

So I checked `docker images` and found indeed two images. I was simply running the wrong image. This is correct
`docker run -p 5000:5000 {imagename-app-exe}`

Man sometimes you don't see the forest.